# Java getting textField.getText() onclick

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to access my other JFrame fields to create an object onclick. Here is my code.

I've searched the internet and all I can find is people referencing textField.getText() in their onclick, but when I compile i

> java:114:error: cannot find symbol.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CharacterCreator extends JFrame{

    public CharacterCreator(){
        final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 600;
        final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;

        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        window.setTitle("Create Character");
        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();

        //panel 1
        JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Human", true);
        JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("Elf");
        JRadioButton radio3 = new JRadioButton("Dwarf");

        ButtonGroup raceGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        raceGroup.add(radio1);
        raceGroup.add(radio2);
        raceGroup.add(radio3);

        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        panel1.add(radio1);
        panel1.add(radio2);
        panel1.add(radio3);


        //panel 2
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
        JTextField nameTextField = new JTextField(15);

        panel2.add(nameLabel);
        panel2.add(nameTextField);

        //panel 3
        JRadioButton radio4 = new JRadioButton("Male", true);
        JRadioButton radio5 = new JRadioButton("Female");

        ButtonGroup genderGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        genderGroup.add(radio4);
        genderGroup.add(radio5);

        panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        panel3.add(radio4);
        panel3.add(radio5);

        //panel 4
        JRadioButton radioWarrior = new JRadioButton("Warrior", true);
        JLabel warriorLabel1 = new JLabel(" The warrior is a battle focused character,");
        JLabel warriorLabel2 = new JLabel("they focuses on strength, defense, and battle tactics.");
        JRadioButton radioThief = new JRadioButton("Thief");
        JLabel thiefLabel1 = new JLabel(" The thief is a stealth focused character,");
        JLabel thiefLabel2 = new JLabel("they focus on agility, cunning, and hope on luck.");
        JRadioButton radioMage = new JRadioButton("Mage");
        JLabel mageLabel1 = new JLabel(" The mage is a magic focused character,");
        JLabel mageLabel2 = new JLabel("they focus on intellegense, wisdom, and mage tools.");

        ButtonGroup professionGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        professionGroup.add(radioWarrior);
        professionGroup.add(radioThief);
        professionGroup.add(radioMage);

        panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,1));
        panel4.add(radioWarrior);
        panel4.add(warriorLabel1);
        panel4.add(warriorLabel2);
        panel4.add(radioThief);
        panel4.add(thiefLabel1);
        panel4.add(thiefLabel2);
        panel4.add(radioMage);
        panel4.add(mageLabel1);
        panel4.add(mageLabel2);

        //panel 5       
        JButton btnCreate = new JButton("Create");      
        btnCreate.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel5.add(btnCreate);

        //add panels
        window.add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        window.add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);
        window.add(panel4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(panel5, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);

        /*character cha = new character();      
        try{

        }catch(Exception e){

        }*/
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //String s = nameTextField.getText();
            //character cha = new character();
            //cha.SetName(nameTextField.getText());
            if(radio1==true){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warrior");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new CharacterCreator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your radio1 variable is declared in constructor i.e. local to a method. How, can a method access the variable declared in another method.

Comment: `if(radio1==true)`? That's not right unless radio1 is a boolean value. It looks like it is a radio button...

Comment: Please Create your TextField variable as attribute of CharacterCreater class or pass in constructor of Listener class. Otherwise, how can you access the variable declared in one method inside other method.

Answer (score -1):

Different class, different scope. Basically nameTextField does not exist in your class ButtonListener. Pass it in through as a parameter.

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
       TextField nameField;
       public ButtonListener(TextField nameField){
             this.nameField = nameField;
       }

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String s = nameField.getText();
             // more action
       }
}
```

When you add ActionListener,

```
//...
btnCreate.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(nameTextField));
```

Also need to pass in your `RadioGroup` as you're trying to access their properties as well.

Comment: not true. the class being an inner class, it belongs to the scope of outer class, and can access whatever is scoped to the outer class. In that case, the `TextField` is scoped to the method, not to the class.

Comment: @njzk2 - replace class in this answer with method and the same concept applies